# how to extract and mapping object from array(object) with redundant key inside key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mapping

i have following example array(object):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "selling",
    "detail": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "sale-report",
        "detail": [
          { "id": 111, "name": "sale-report1", "detail": [] },
          { "id": 112, "name": "sale-report2", "detail": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "webstore",
    "detail": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "sale-report",
        "detail": [
          { "id": 111, "name": "webstore-report1", "detail": [] },
          { "id": 112, "name": "webstore-report2", "detail": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "setting",
    "detail": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "general",
        "detail": [
          { "id": 111, "name": "setting-general1", "detail": [] },
          { "id": 112, "name": "setting-general2", "detail": [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

how to change the array with new format like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "selling",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "sale-report"
  },
  { "id": 111, "name": "sale-report1" },
  { "id": 112, "name": "sale-report2" },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "webstore",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "sale-report",
  },
  { "id": 111, "name": "webstore-report1" },
  { "id": 112, "name": "webstore-report2" },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "setting",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "general",
  },
  { "id": 111, "name": "setting-general1" },
  { "id": 112, "name": "setting-general2" }
]
```

with the condition that if there is a key "detail" inside object in the branch, it will be mapped as well (assuming unlimited key "detail" inside object inside array)

note: content of detail will be same as parent, but different value

thanks in advance

i tried mapping mannualy with foreach, but i cant figure out if detail key with array(object) has unlimited nesting

Comment: In your expected output, many items have the same id. Would it not cause any issues?

Comment: in real case, id would be unique

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the objects and take `detail` out of the object and map the rest object and the results of nested details array as flat array with a recursive function.

```js
const
    flat = (array = []) => array.flatMap(({ detail, ...rest }) => [
        rest,
        ...flat(detail)
    ]),
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "selling", detail: [{ id: 11, name: "sale-report", detail: [{ id: 111, name: "sale-report1", detail: [] }, { id: 112, name: "sale-report2", detail: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, name: "webstore", detail: [{ id: 11, name: "sale-report", detail: [{ id: 111, name: "webstore-report1", detail: [] }, { id: 112, name: "webstore-report2", detail: [] }] }] }, { id: 2, name: "setting", detail: [{ id: 11, name: "general", detail: [{ id: 111, name: "setting-general1", detail: [] }, { id: 112, name: "setting-general2", detail: [] }] }] }],
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion) to do this.

Here is the working demo-

```js
let input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "selling",
    detail: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "sale-report",
        detail: [
          { id: 111, name: "sale-report1", detail: [] },
          { id: 112, name: "sale-report2", detail: [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "webstore",
    detail: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "sale-report",
        detail: [
          { id: 111, name: "webstore-report1", detail: [] },
          { id: 112, name: "webstore-report2", detail: [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "setting",
    detail: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "general",
        detail: [
          { id: 111, name: "setting-general1", detail: [] },
          { id: 112, name: "setting-general2", detail: [] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let result = [];

function parseData(arr) {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    result.push({
      id: item.id || null,
      name: item.name || null
    });

    if (item.detail && item.detail.length) {
      parseData(item.detail);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

let output = parseData(input);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

A non recursive method of doing this could look something like the following:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"selling","detail":[{"id":11,"name":"sale-report","detail":[{"id":111,"name":"sale-report1","detail":[]},{"id":112,"name":"sale-report2","detail":[]}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"webstore","detail":[{"id":11,"name":"sale-report","detail":[{"id":111,"name":"webstore-report1","detail":[]},{"id":112,"name":"webstore-report2","detail":[]}]}]},{"id":2,"name":"setting","detail":[{"id":11,"name":"general","detail":[{"id":111,"name":"setting-general1","detail":[]},{"id":112,"name":"setting-general2","detail":[]}]}]}];

const extract = (data) => {
  const result = [];
  const queue = [...data];
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    const { detail, ...rest } = queue.shift();
    
    result.push(rest);
    queue.unshift(...detail);
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(extract(data));
```